# Number of Violinists in Orchestra

Tags: violin

Please help me regarding this classic song sung by Rod Stewart with the Orchestra.

Will the song music make a difference if the number of violinists are increased or decreased?

If yes, what will be the impact to the song?

Increased - Impact?
Decreased - Impact?

If no Impact, why?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about why you're asking. As currently stated, its unlikely to receive an answer beyond the one @PiedPiper linked.

Comment: @aaron well there technical​ly will be the answer : "yes, it has an impact to the song".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to this: how many *voices* you have, and how many instruments play unison per voice. Convention is to have the violins split up in two voices (plus the similar violas, and cellos and basses), but each voice can be split up further (called “divisi”), which of course means less per unison-note.

The number of voices is mostly a compositional question, i.e. what harmonical / counterpuntal complexity you want. The number of instruments per voice affects more rather subtly the sound timbre.

The difference between 10 and 15 violins is marginal. 5 will sound notably different: obviously a bit less gradiose, more intimate, but if the players are good it will still be a good smooth and silky string sound. Even 3 can still have that effect; only when you reduce it to 2 that doesn't quite work any more (then, the small pitch deviations become a noticeable phasing / beat, rather than everything blending smoothly together), and a single violin just sounds completely different from an ensemble.

Comment: Thanks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_string_violin A combination of 5 string and 4 string violins used by Violinists can also make a difference in the song music played at the Orchestra? . In this song, Will there be a difference?

Comment: Fivestring violins are uncommon in the orchestra and don't really offer any advantages there. They basically sound like a normal violin and are a bit more difficult to play, in exchange for covering also the range of the viola. Which means you could put a fivestring violin in the viola section and it would probably blend in just fine, though a proper viola will have a fuller sound in the lower range.

Comment: Thank you. So a combination of 4,5,6,7,8,9 strings violins played at the orchestra by the violinists for this song will make very little difference to this song?

Comment: I've never seen a violin with more than 5 strings. (Though there's [a related instrument with sympathetic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardanger_fiddle), but used very differently.)

Comment: Thanks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_string_violin The Wiki reference states 5,6,7,8,9 strings violins. Aren't they designed & constructed?

Comment: Thanks. Wiki reference to Five string violin - (Six and seven string electric violins also exist, adding lower strings tuned to F and B♭.) (8 & 9 String versions add on a Low Eb, & a High A from a Soprano Violin String set.)

Comment: Those are oddities, and not played by any normal violinists. With electric instruments you can do a lot more than acoustics ones, but they aren't meant for ensemble playing.

Comment: Thanks. Which is more easy to learn and play? Acoustic or Electric Violin? If one learns and play the Acoustic Violin, will it be easy to learn and play the Electric violin and vice versa is also equally true?

Comment: Well, acoustic is very much still the default. Most players start acoustic and then maybe explore electric later on. Electric isn't easier per se, but it's easier to add effects that will smudge over small mistakes/inaccuracies – which may make it less frustrating to learn, but can also result in getting used to bad playing technique.

Comment: Thanks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestra In this classic song, how it is decided by the conductor or concert master, as how many total number of violinists will be playing the violin ensemble? I mean how it is evaluated coming to the actual total number of violinists taking part in the Orchestra? Example : If it is 20 violinists, how 20 is traced?.

Comment: Honestly, what it ultimately depends on is mostly how many violinists they can/want afford to pay. And how prestigious the event is, ensuring that there are enough to look appropriately glamorous. (Or, in an amateur setting the constraint may be the other way around: they accept as many violinists as the venue has space to seat.)

Comment: Thank you. So it depends upon the factors such as Venue Hall Stage size capacity, Violinists availability, Violinist payment dues?. The exact Number of Violinists required in a orchestra music song can be mathematically derived ? Example for this classic song, what would be the exact total number of violinists required to get the best effects for hearing from the audience point of view?

Comment: Yes. — No. — There is no “exact total number”.

Comment: Thank you. The number of violinists ensemble required at the orchestra can be derived scientifically or mathematically? Do you mean the same song played in different orchestras at different venues will not have a constant (Fixed) number of violinists but a variable number of violinists?

Comment: **No**, it can't be derived scientifically. Please stop asking.

Comment: Thank you. But isn' it interesting as from the end user experience viewing and hearing the same song at four different venues will be different? Since it is a variable, the number of violinists are not fixed, it could be 5,10,15,20, the end user experience will be then different. Example : The Orchestra venues are New York, Chicago, New Jersey & Los Angeles. You will get different experiences as the number of violinists are varying at four different venues.

Comment: The experience will _anyway_ be different at different venues, because every venue has different room acoustics.

Comment: I would add that "voice" is used here in a sense that is more or less synonymous with "part." I suppose some people with less exposure to classical music theory would be unfamiliar with this meaning of "voice."